# React select specific ref

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I need to select that one paragraph with class description when clicked on 'Click me' link, then I will add class to this paragraph.
I tried to do it with e.currentTarget + previousSibling, but it didn`t work.
How to do it in React TS?
My code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Item } from '../types';


interface Props {
    handleData: (item: Item) => void;
}

const CartList = (props: Props) => {
    const description = useRef(null)
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);

    const showMore = (e: Event) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`./list.json`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setItems(data))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }, []);

    return (
        <main className="container">
            <ul className="row item-list">
                {items.map((item: Item, index: number) => (
                    <li key={item.id} className="col-xl-3 item">
                        <div className="item-wrap p-3">
                            <p
                                className="item-description"
                                ref={description}
                            >
                                {item.description}
                            </p>
                            <a href="." onClick={(e: any) => showMore(e)}>
                                Click me
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </main>
    );
};

export default CartList;
```

Comment: In your showMore you can use the ref attached to do something like description.current.classList.toggle("your-class"); so everytime you click that button you will either show or hide that css class

Comment: Problem is, that React find the last ref of type "description", so this class won`t be toggled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like

`const [yourClass, setYourClass] = useState('Name Before')`

with an onClick like `onClick={setClicked('Name after')}`, inside the button

---

And then just make sure the class is set to `yourClass`

Answer (score 0):

I know how to toggle class to element, but I don`t know, how to assign it to the correct element.  Let say I have 5 elements and I click on button in first of them. The class should be assigned to the paragraph one, but React find the last existence of ref "description", so the class will be on last paragraph. And it is not correct.